# Inserting Active Record Data into Yii's CGRidView widget

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii-components, zii-widgets

I have a table in mysql that I want to display with the `CGridView` widget.  Here is my code thus far:

My Controller file (snipped of course):

```
public function actionIndex()
{
  //call the AR table model
  $model = new ViewResults();
  //This generates a simple "SELECT * FROM table statment".
  $list = $model->findAll();
  $this->render('index', array('list'=>$list));
}
```

My View file looks like(snipped):

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$list,
 )); ?>
```

I'm getting the following error:

Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in C:\xampp\framework\zii\widgets\CBaseListView.php on line 105

Here is the source code to the [CBaseListView.php](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.7/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php) file.

I'm pretty sure I'm screwing up by putting the list object in the widget.  Is there something I have to do to `$list` before I pass it to the widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CActiveDataProvider Yii's Class.
Something like this:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('model', array(
  'criteria'=>array(
    'order'=>'column1',
  ),
));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'id'=>'my-grid',
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  'columns'=>array(
    'column1',
    'column2',
    'column3',
    array(
      'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
  ),
));
```

Where model is your model and columns your columns.

Comment: Would the new CActiveDataProvider call be in the view with the widget?

Comment: Answering my own comment: no.  You call the dataprovider in the controller and pass the variable to the view.  This worked.  Thank you sir.

Comment: that's totally wrong. you do not need to use a CActiveDataProvider

Comment: It's not totally wrong.  I changed the "have to" to "can".  You can use either.  "totally wrong" is far to extreme as was your downvote.  You should have just edited his question.  I didn't end up using findall.  I used his example that just requires you to pass the AR model.

Answer (score 3):

findAll() returns an *array*, whereas CActiveDataProvider returns a dataProvider.

If you want to use find all, all you have to do is convert the array using CArrayDataProvider

example:

```
<?
php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>new CArrayDataProvider($list, array()),
 )); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CArrayDataProvider is also a option. But the sorting is easy to do when it comes from CActiveDataProvider.

Comment: I'd delete this answer and just write it as a comment under your original.